# Can I call a variable in a prompt to store the value of the variable into a prompt section

Tags: python, prompt, openai-api

```
import os
from urllib import response
import openai

def gpt3(stext):
    openai.api_key = 'my-kye-here'

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-002",
        prompt= stext,
            temperature=0.7,
            max_tokens=256,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0
    )
    content = response.choices[0].text.split('.')
    #print(content)
    return response.choices[0].text


stext = input("Enter your prompt")
response = gpt3(stext)
print(response)
```

This is my Python code in which I'm using OpenAI API, So where I used `prompt = stext,` , I want to use the prompt like that `prompt = "My rest prompt: Here I need to call my stext variable",`does this make any sense? My prompt is written permanently in the prompt section, can I use stext variable in the prompt in case to get the value that user put in the stext in the prompt section? I'm not sure I'm asking it in the right way or not, but if you got my point, then please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you change the code to what you have described?